# Add Main Tab Bar to Other View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I'm a new Swift developer.  I'm using Swift 4.2 and XCode 10.2.

I have a tab bar controller with 5 tab bar items.  In the view controller for each tab bar item there is a button to show the balance in a different view controller (call it the Balance View Controller).  I have a segue from each button to the Balance View Controller.

I am using interface builder, but will be happy to add code.

How can I put the main tab bar on the Balance View Controller so when the user is done viewing the balance, he can select another tab bar item and keep going?  I rejected using a navigation controller because the back button will interfere with the uniform view at the top of every screen and I don't want to adjust it.

I could not find any SO questions that address this issue.  And all the other web resources I found are very basic on how to implement tab bars.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can someone explain why the downvoting?  Is it a style issue?  Too much a noobie question?  I'd like to learn to prevent the same in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

Load `Balance View Controller` as a Child ViewController, and display its view on top of the current view. This will leave the tab bar alone, allowing users to navigate to another tab.

`Balance View Controller` sounds like it's just an information display. If so, you can add a tap gesture to remove it from the current view on a simple tap.

If `Balance View Controller` is interactive, you can add a button to remove it from the current view.

Since you say you have a button in each tab's VC to show the `Balance View Controller`, then you probably also want to remove it from the current view when another tab is selected.

Comment: Yes.  This is what I'm finding.  If I embed a navigation controller and hide it, when I get to Balance View Controller and select a different tab (other than the tab I came from) I go to that new tab.  But when I select that tab that first took me to the Balance View Controller - the Balance View Controller is still there!  I have to tap that same tab icon again to get back to the view controller for that tab.

Comment: Can I remove the child from the view in `ViewWillDisappear`?  That way in the Balance View Controller I can always remove it before going to any other tab?

Comment: Thanks.  I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: `BalanceViewController` has a tableview.  I keep getting an error that the `tableview.datasource` (which is self) is nil.  I tried setting it with the instance of the `BalanceViewController` in the parent and several other methods, but it is always the same error.  I see in the documentation for child view controllers that the parent controls the data, but I can't figure out how to let the `BalanceViewController` be its own datasource.  A segue from another VC in the storyboard shows the `BalanceViewController` properly, so I know that it is not broken.  Here's the code to set up the child:

Comment: let parent = self
        let balanceVC = BalanceViewController()
        parent.view.addSubview(balanceVC.view)
        parent.addChild(balanceVC)
        balanceVC.didMove(toParent: parent)

Comment: By combining your solution with @Razi Tiwana's solution I got it to work.  I embedded the viewcontrollers in a navigation controller and then removed the `BalanceViewController` as a child in the `viewWillDisappear` method of the `BalanceViewController`.  Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

> I rejected using a navigation controller because the back button will interfere with the uniform view at the top of every screen and I don't want to adjust it.

The best way to achieve this is with a `UINavigationController` what we can do about the Top navigation bar and the darn `back button` is we can hide the whole thing by

```
// Add this to your viewcontroller
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

And going further if you want to you can disable the animations for the view controller

hope this helps

Comment: If the back button is hidden, how do I go back to the previous view controller?

Comment: I thought you didn't want the back button, okay so you must be using `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` to get back on a button tap, now you can use `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: Thank you.  I wanted to use the main tab bar instead of any additional buttons since the only places you can go in the app, other than the Balance View Controller, are listed on the tab bar.  But I don't see a way to do it.  If I have to add a back button, I will use your suggestion.

Comment: I think I misunderstood.  When I use the hidden navigation controller, it keeps the tab bar at the bottom.  I can keep navigating through the app with the tab bar and I don't need the back button.  I will keep testing and mark as the answer.

Comment: @TMLynch Yes the tab bar will remain at the bottom, and glad to help :)